# Using boost::shared_ptr with classes that overload the subscript operator ([])

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, operator-keyword, subscript

I have a class that overloads the subscript operator:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

   int& operator[] (const int idx)
   {
      return someArray[idx];
   }  

private:

   int someArray[10];
};
```

This of course allows me to access the array elements of the someArray member like so:

```
SomeClass c;
int x = c[0];
```

However, some instances of SomeClass will be wrapped in a boost shared pointer:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SomeClass> p(new SomeClass);
```

However, in order to use the subscript operator I have to use a more verbose syntax that kind of defeats the succinctness of the subscript operator overload:

```
int x = p->operator[](0);
```

Is there any way to access the subscript operator in a more shorthand manner for such instances?

Comment: How about `(*p)[0]`? It isn't great, but it is shorter.

Comment: You could bind a reference to the stored object: `SomeClass& obj = *p; int x = obj[0];`.

Comment: @juanchopanza A schoolboy error on my part, I tried your solution earlier but was dereferencing the pointer outside the brackets, hence the compilation error I was getting. Thanks for putting me back on track.

Comment: @DyP Thanks, that didn't occur to me. I can see that coming in useful for large code blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both juanchopanzaand DyP have answered my question sufficiently. After googling regarding the etiquette for answers found in comments, it was suggested to post a self-answer referencing the correct answers in the comments in order to close the question (I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer, though).

juanchopanza's answer is as follows:

```
int x = (*p)[0];
```

DyP's answer is as follows:

```
SomeClass& obj = *p;
int x = obj[0];
```

Thank you both for your contributions.